# Log scale for Bokeh bar chart

Tags: bokeh

My code is below. How can I get a log scale for a bokeh hbar plot? Tried `x_axis_type="log"`, but that returned an empty plot.

*Edit*: I was advised that I must set `left` to a low but non-zero value in order for it to work, but the new addition `left = 0.001` in the code below seem to offset the zero point of the bars on the left, but does not appear as a desired log-scale where the difference between the extreme value in `x` is visualised as less visually extreme.

*Edit (solved)*: My error in the edit above was that I had not explicitly set the range of the bars. I added `x_range=[0.001,1000000]` to the code below, and now I get the desired result. See image.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

x = [1,5,9,256000]
y = ["a","b","c","d"]

p = figure(y_range=y,x_axis_type = "log",x_range=[0.001,1000000])

p.hbar(y = y, right = x, left = 0.001, height = 0.1)
show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: It' not really clear waht the question is. You can explicity set the range start and end for the axis, if that is what you are asking. If you are saying you don't like the results with a small left value, then you might be advised to look at a different tool besides Bokeh for this specific use, since Bokeh does not support actual zero data values on a log scale in any capacity.

Comment: Thanks. I now explicitly set the start and end for the axis (edited in the original post), and I get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Zero is not a permissible value on a log scale, and as of version 2.3.1 Bokeh does not have anything like Matplotlib's `symlog` scale that linearizes around the origin. The best you will be able to to is to set `left` equal to some very small value (but non-zero).

Comment: Do you mean like this? `p.hbar(y = y, right = x, left = 0.00001)`? Does not give the desired result.

Comment: Well, you should update your question then, to state 1) what your desired result is in detail, and 2) how the result you actually got differs from that. You always need to provide detailed and specific information, otherwise it is impossible to offer guidance.

Comment: I have edited the original question above.